# inherit textBox_MouseMove event from class in form1 c#

Tags: c#

I have created class in which i have defined methods which i need to call in forms .I need to call this methods from class Test in many forms.Below is my code how i try, but without success.I dont see here where i'm wrong.

```
  //class Test.cs
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Drawing.Printing;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.Xml;
 using System.Xml.Linq;

   namespace Restaurant
  {
public class Test : Form
{

    public  void MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt = sender as TextBox;
        foreach (TextBox text in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                if (txt.Name == text.Name)
                {
                    txt.Left = e.X + txt.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
                    txt.Top = e.Y + txt.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
        }
    }
  }
 }



 // form in which i need to call methods from Test class
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Drawing.Printing;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.Xml;
 using System.Xml.Linq;

  namespace Restaurant
  {
public partial class Form1 : Test
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    private void textBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Test b = new Test();
        b.MouseMove1(sender,e);

    }

    private void textBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Test b = new Test();
        b.MouseDown(sender,e);

    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Form1 inherits from Test, you should be able to change Form1 as follows:

```
private void textBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MouseMove1(sender,e);
}
```

This way you are calling the method on the form you are on, rather than a new form that you are instantiating and acting against in your code sample.

Comment: and how to call another method which has no paramether to return?

Comment: I would post a new question that shows what you are trying to accomplish.